# Heroku SSL Endpoint - "No Such App"

Tags: ssl, heroku, endpoint

Any ideas why I might be getting the "No Such App" error when I go to my herokussl.com URL (after adding a cert and Heroku SSL endpoint)?

I followed the instructions here (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint), and got a herokussl.com URL.

I really don't think it's a DNS issue - as I haven't even gotten to that step.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears you can't access sites directly through the herokussl.com - which kinda makes sense, since they already provide wildcard ssl on herokuapp.com. I've just tried this with a production site I have which uses SSL and get the same "No Such App" if i access the herokussl.com domain directly.

If you CNAME your custom domain to the herokussl.com domain that were provided or from `heroku certs` and make sure you've added the custom domain to your application via `heroku domains:add <customdomain>` then it works fine.

Comment: What he said.  You cannot browse direct to a `herokussl.com` domain as the routing won't work.  You need a custom domain.

Comment: Your answer actually got me thinking...when I added the herokussl.com address as a domain for the app, it worked!

Comment: The Heroku docs say you can however, "If you have a herokussl.com endpoint URL, visit it via https, e.g., https://tokyo-2121.herokussl.com."  The docs say you'll get a cert error, not that you'll get a "No Such App" error.