# Heroku SSL using self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, certificate

Following steps of: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint
I have added SSL Endpoint add-on into my server hosted on Heroku.

Then, I've created a self signed certificate following: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self

At this point I have upload my self-signed cert and private key using:

```
heroku certs:add server.crt server.key
```

In fact it gaves me:

```
 !    Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format.
```

But I found a simple solution on Google:

`openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key.rsa`

Then I 've uploaded all:

```
heroku certs:add server.crt server.key.rsa
Resolving trust chain... done
Adding SSL Endpoint to <myapp>... done
<myapp> now served by wakayama-xxxx.herokussl.com
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): <mydomain>
Expires At:     2016-09-29 11:24 UTC
Issuer:         /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/CN=<mydomain>
Starts At:      2015-09-30 11:24 UTC
Subject:        /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/CN=<mydomain>
SSL certificate is self signed.
```

So if I ask for my certificates into Heroku I get:

```
heroku certs:info
Fetching SSL Endpoint wakayama-xxxx.herokussl.com info for <myapp>... done
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): <mydomain>
Expires At:     2016-09-29 11:24 UTC
Issuer:         /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/CN=<mydomain>
Starts At:      2015-09-30 11:24 UTC
Subject:        /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/CN=<mydomain>
SSL certificate is self signed.
```

So seems that all is ok. Except... if I go to wakayama-xxxx.herokussl.com I see the message: "Heroku | No such app", hum, I've guess It should me redirect to my app, but not.

Any ideas?

Comment: I saw people recommending to add the SSL domain using: "heroku domain:add wakayama-xxxx.herokussl.com" but when I try it I get: Can't add an additional Heroku domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like: [Heroku SSL Endpoint - "No Such App"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100786/heroku-ssl-endpoint-no-such-app)

So I've closed my eyes and I've changed my DNS to add a CNAME pointing to wakayama-xxxx.herokussl.com (which doesn't redirect to app) and magically now HTTPS works. If someone can explain what's happening here I would appreciate.

Comment: I think the certificate is served by the heroku router before the client request ever hits your web dyno.  By adding the CNAME, when the browser inspects the certificate and goes looking into the IP records returned by DNS, for confirmation, it finds a match, and thus lives happily thereafter.